# Getting CM-CFG-5024 error on content store upgrade when upgrading to Cognos BI 10.2.2

Tags: upgrade, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Tried to upgrade one Cognos instance from 10.2.1 -> 10.2.2

Existing 10.2.1 works just fine.

Uninstalled 10.2.1 and installed 10.2.2 as per documentation. When trying to start the Cognos service i get a message i haven't seen before during upgrade.

CM-CFG-5024

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you find the files it's referring to on your machine?

Comment: Yes they are there and i checked folder permissions also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to do the upgrade is to export the whole Content Store. Upgrade with a new/empty database and reimport the content.

This procedure will help guide you for the export and import the Content Store:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21340892

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an open defect for the symptoms you see.

```
PI47878 - UNABLE TO UPGRADE AN IBM COGNOS 10.2.1 FP8 CONTENT STORE TO10.2.2
```

Here is the link from [IBM SUPPORT PORTAL](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1PI47878)